# Format nsnumber for user defined currency format

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnumberformatter

I need to format a NSNumber based on some data and user options. 
First the user need to select the grouping separator ( "," or "." or none ) , if the grouping separator is "," than the decimal separator will be "." , and vice versa... The number is a currency that is stored with it's international currency code (USD for dollar , EUR for euro etc)... If the currency has a symbol it should be put in front of the number, if not that the code will replace that .

So 1234.50 should look like 
$ 1,234.50 -- if the currency is USD and the grouping separator is ","
$ 1.234,50 -- if the seppareteor is set as "."
and RON 1,234.50 if the currency code is RON (it has no currency symbol) ... 
I understand that NSNumberFormatter relies on the iPhone's settings ... this may NOT be the case here, as the user can change the format inside the app ... Any good ideas how to do this ?

I tried

```
- (NSString *)getFormatedNumber:(NSNumber *)number withCurrency:(NSString *)currencyAbrev andMode:(NSUInteger)mode
{

    NSNumberFormatter *formater = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [formater setCurrencyCode:currencyAbrev];

    if (mode == 1) {
        [formater setGroupingSize:3];
        [formater setGroupingSeparator:@","];
    }else {
        [formater setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
        [formater setGroupingSize:3];
    }



    return [formater stringFromNumber:number];
}
```

with these being the calls

```
 self.label1.text = [[PSCurrencyDisplay sharedInstance] getFormatedNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:12345.67f] withCurrency:@"USD" andMode:1];
    self.label2.text = [[PSCurrencyDisplay sharedInstance] getFormatedNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:12345.67f] withCurrency:@"EUR" andMode:2];
```

The result was ... quite bad ....

Comment: Saying 'The result was "quite bad"' isn't the most helpful thing you could put in the question. How about you actually show us the result?

Comment: 12346 was the result ... I have no idea where that came from